# How to write symbols that require Alt Gr on Android emulator

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am trying to fill an EditText through the Android Emulator using my computer's keyboard. I can type everything I want excepted characters that require Alt Gr (like "@"). Nothing happens when I make a combination of Alt Gr + something.

Is there a way to enable that in the emulator ?

Comment: It's still open bug in Google issue tracker from 2017 ‍♂️ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37142228

Answer (score 0):

Use the virtual keyboard inside the emulator is in the lower right corner in the phone's screen.